# Pivot chart count number of serial samples not repeated samples

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an excel database that consist of ID, Name and Sample Date.  I made a pivot table to count the number of names and samples each name has but I want a count of the number of serial samples each name has, not including repeated samples.

Here is an example database:

```
 ID    Name     Sample Date
M1.1    A     8/2/2013
M2.1a   B     8/6/2013
M2.1b   B     8/6/2013
M2.1c   A     8/6/2013
M1.2    A     8/7/2013
M3.1    C     8/9/2013
M4.1    D     8/10/2013
M1.3    A     8/11/2013
M2.2    B     8/13/2013
```

I want the pivot table to be able to count that A has 4 serial samples, B has 2 serial samples instead of 3, C has 1, and D has 1.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Exclusion is based on using only the first of the repeated samples on the same date, so for B, M2.1b is excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant but for want of any other answer so far:

Add a helper column containing `=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,C2)` and copy down to suit. Order on that helper column and restrict the PivotTable range to include only half of those entries that show up as duplicates.